# how to parse this JSONArray

Tags: android, json

Hi guys i have this `JSONObject` I'm having hard time to parse it.

Here's the `JSON`,

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 2,
        "created": "2016-11-07T15:29:47Z",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "results": {
            "rate": [{
                "id": "USDINR",
                "Name": "USD/INR",
                "Rate": "66.7700",
                "Date": "11/7/2016",
                "Time": "3:27pm",
                "Ask": "66.8000",
                "Bid": "66.7700"
            }, {
                "id": "USDEUR",
                "Name": "USD/EUR",
                "Rate": "0.9060",
                "Date": "11/7/2016",
                "Time": "3:29pm",
                "Ask": "0.9065",
                "Bid": "0.9060"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see above there are two "Rate" I want to store first "Rate" to a String array called `Result[0]` and second "Rate" to `Result[1]`.

Here what I'm trying.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(JSON);

JSONObject rateObject = object.getJSONObject("rate");
JSONArray rateArray = rateObject.getJSONArray("Rate");
result[0] = rateArray.getString(0);
result[1] = rateArray.getString(1);
```

I know maybe I'm doing this like stupid. So please help me out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONArray rateArray = new JSONObject(JSON)
    .getJSONObject("query")
    .getJSONObject("results")
    .getJSONArray("rate");
result[0] = rateArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("Rate");
result[1] = rateArray.getJSONObject(1).getString("Rate");
```

Comment: Sorry Still confuse

Comment: Tried to clarify the example, what do you struggle with?

Comment: what do you expect `rateArray[0]` to do?

Answer (score 0):

To Get the array I would try this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(JSON);
JSONObject rateObject = object.getJSONObject("results");
JSONArray rateArray = rateObject.getJSONArray("rate");
```

And then use a for to read all objects in the array:

```
int length = rateArray.length();
for (int i =0; i < length; i++){
    JSONObject rate = rateArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String rateResult = rate.getString("Rate");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatted JSON looks like this

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "count":2,
      "created":"2016-11-07T15:29:47Z",
      "lang":"en-US",
      "results":{  
         "rate":[  
            {  
               "id":"USDINR",
               "Name":"USD/INR",
               "Rate":"66.7700",
               "Date":"11/7/2016",
               "Time":"3:27pm",
               "Ask":"66.8000",
               "Bid":"66.7700"
            },
            {  
               "id":"USDEUR",
               "Name":"USD/EUR",
               "Rate":"0.9060",
               "Date":"11/7/2016",
               "Time":"3:29pm",
               "Ask":"0.9065",
               "Bid":"0.9060"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

To get the `rate` array you have to this

```
JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray rateArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONArray("rate");
```

Then query `rate` array like this

```
JSONObject rateJSON = (JSONObject)rateArray.get(index);
String id = rateJSON.getString("id"); //Or any other field of rate
```

Comment: Replace index with 0 or 1, etc depending on the size of your rate array.

Comment: Replaced with 1 now its saying incompatible type required: org.json.JSONObject found: java.lang.obj

Comment: Where are you getting this exception? On this line `JSONObject rateJSON = (JSONObject)rateArray.get(index)`. Are you casting to JSONObject?

Answer (score 0):

Anthony,
You need to go from the root element ( query ) to the "rate" node :

```
JSONArray rates =  object.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONArray("rate")

result[0] = rates.getJSONObject(0).get("Rate")
result[1] = rates.getJSONObject(1).get("Rate")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONObject queryObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("query");
JSONObject resultObj = queryObj.getJSONObject("results");
JSONArray rateArr = resultObj.getJSONArray("rate");

result[0] = rateArr.getJSONObject(0).getString("Rate");
result[1] = rateArr.getJSONObject(1).getString("Rate");
```